# Meaning of "sawtooth" ping times?

Tags: networking

My current ping is as follows

```
PING google.com (173.194.32.46): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 173.194.32.46: icmp_seq=0 ttl=54 time=636.160 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.46: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=557.518 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.46: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=171.721 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.46: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=92.592 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.46: icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=628.561 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.46: icmp_seq=5 ttl=54 time=550.030 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.46: icmp_seq=6 ttl=54 time=164.029 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.46: icmp_seq=7 ttl=54 time=85.310 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.46: icmp_seq=8 ttl=54 time=740.611 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.46: icmp_seq=9 ttl=54 time=541.482 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.46: icmp_seq=10 ttl=54 time=155.391 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.46: icmp_seq=11 ttl=54 time=76.073 ms
```

I've never seen anything like this. It's a "sawtooth" like behavior. I see it also on other websites, so I think it's either my provider, or my network. Do you have any insight on this ?

Comment: periodic activity of other processes? Find out what's happening with that frequenccy

Comment: I'm not doing anything at the moment. It's just my laptop. I just restarted the ADSL router and now I have consistent 112 ms, so it might be the router, but still I'm quite interested at what could produce something like this.

Comment: some other app in the network that lost its connection with the restart?

Comment: Could be. Good point. Please add it as an answer.